# Issues connecting to Socket Mobile scanner using SDK and iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9.3, socketscan

I'm having an issue with the scanner, not sure if it's my iPhone 6s, the iOS version 9.3 or the scanner in itself (Socket Cordless Hand Scanner 7Mi).

I was able to integrate CocoaPods and the ScanApiSDK library, everything compiled correctly, then I added some logic using this [example](https://github.com/SocketMobile/singleentryswift-ios/blob/master/SingleEntrySwift/MasterViewController.swift) and connected the scanner via bluetooth, but having an issue when detecting scanners connected. When I do `scanApi.isScanApiOpen()` it returns true, but `scanApi.isDeviceConnected()` returns false and `scanApi.getDevicesList()` returns and empty object.
However, if I open the notes app and read a barcode, it types the code in text correctly (which I believe is the HID mode).

I've searched everywhere but I don't seem to get anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned you think the scanner might still be in HID mode. Does the barcode data show up if you select a text input in Safari and scan something? Do you remember scanning a barcode to put your 7Mi into iOS mode?

Comment: @Enrico Yeah I think that might be my problem, the first time I paired the device I didn't read any barcode. So it directly went into HID mode. I just learned that there is a reset barcode, so I'm trying that just now to see what happens, and then I'll scan the iOS barcode before pairing again.

Comment: Ok, after you reset the scanner and put it in iOS mode, make sure you delete the pairing on your iOS device before you try to pair the scanner again

Comment: Thanks @Enrico. I think I got it working after deleting the pairing on my iPhone, doing the factory reset, and pairing again after scanning the iOS mode barcode. It will be a little difficult to explain what is the exact process for pairing to the client unfortunately :( I wish there was a way to switch to iOS mode even if you have entered into HID mode before.

Comment: Excellent. Unfortunately, you need to scan that one barcode before pairing your scanner - but other than that, the pairing process is the same as any other Bluetooth device. Since you found the solution yourself, would you like to post your answer and claim the good karma?